# Is it necessary to write the 'master' in 'git push origin master' since origin already means the master branch in the remote repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I was wondering whether the master is even necessary because doesn't origin already mean the master branch on the remote repo?

Thank you so much for your help, you are awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premise of your question is wrong: `origin` *does not* mean a particular branch.  More specifically, the word `origin` in `git push origin` or `git fetch origin` (or any similar command) appears in the place where the command wants something called a *remote*, not in the place where the command wants a branch name.

A *remote* is ... well, it has multiple purposes, but the *main* one is that it is a short name for a URL.  Suppose the URL is:

```
https://github.com/someverylongusername/anotherverylongrepositoryname.git
```

Which is easier to type, the above, or `origin`?  Git lets you use `origin` to *mean* `https://...`, without having to type in `https://...`.

Now, if you run:

```
git push
```

and leave off *both* `origin` *and* the branch name, Git makes two assumptions:<sup>1</sup>

1. "I, Git, should find the remote associated with the *current branch name*."
2. "I, Git, should use the *current branch name* as the branch name."

Note that both of these use (and thus require) the *current branch name*.  The current branch name is the one you have checked out now, because you ran:

```
git switch foobranch
```

or:

```
git checkout barbranch
```

or whatever.  If your most recent switch or checkout was to `master`, then the *current branch name* **is** `master`, and you're probably all set.  You can run `git push`, or `git push origin`: including `origin` tells Git that the remote in question is `origin`, so it can skip step 1, but it still executes step 2 here.

Now, there are several cases where you *can't* omit the remote and/or the branch name.  And, because the remote name *always comes first*, if you *must* provide the branch name, you must *also* provide the remote name.  For instance, if you're currently on your `feature/new`, but you want to *push* your `feature/old`, you have two options:

- switch to `feature/old` and run `git push` with no arguments, or
- run `git push origin feature/old`—you can't omit the `origin` *or* the `feature/old` here, even though you really should only need to specify `feature/old`.

Where this all gets very confusing is the fact that when you have a *remote*, you have *remote-tracking names*.<sup>2</sup>  That is, if you have a remote named `origin`, you probably *also* have the names `origin/master` or `origin/main`, plus `origin/feature/new` and so on.  These names all start with `origin/`, which helps you remember that these are your own Git repository's *copy* of the names your Git software saw over in the GitHub Git repository when your Git called up the GitHub software and said to look into the GitHub repository.

(Does that all make sense?  You might have to read it through a few times.  With clones being so similar, it's like being at a party where everyone is named Bruce.  Bruce told Bruce to tell Bruce that Bruce was looking for Bruce.  That's clear and obvious, right?  Those are five different people.)

Now, there's a place where you can use `origin` where Git is looking for a *branch or similar name*, and in *this* case, `origin` means `origin/HEAD`, and `origin/HEAD` is what Git calls a *symbolic reference*.  But that's not the case with your basic `git push` here.

---

<sup>1</sup>These two assumptions are only the default since Git 2.0, but Git 1.x is now more than a decade old and only a few systems still have it.  But you can *configure* Git to act the old way.  It's also worth mentioning here that `git push` with no arguments, when `push.default` is set to `simple` as it is since Git 2.0, this only works if the current branch has an *upstream* set.  But this is getting into another—albeit related—question entirely.

<sup>2</sup>Git documentation officially calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  I like to leave out the word *branch* since these are demonstrably *not* actual *branch* names.  They're just *copied from* branch names, as seen in some other repository.  Old Git documentation is squirrelly about what to call them, too, so people tend to use a lot of mixed terms here.

Comment: @torek, I know you do not like the "remote-tracking _branches_" terminology, but I think you should still mention it in your answers, because that's what the Git documentation refers to :)

Comment: @philb: valid point, added

Comment: @torek - I'll wait for "Pro Gitboy book" from your posts here. It **will be** (SIC!) really useful, sure

Comment: Maybe 2. "I, Git, should use the current branch name as the branch name <on the remote>"?

Comment: @tymtam: no, it uses the current branch name as the *refspec*, which means that it's on *both machines*. A full refspec has an optional leading plus sign, a "source" name, a colon, and a "destination" name, as in `git push origin mine:theirs` or `git push origin refs/heads/mine:refs/tags/v1.2` for instance. For `git push` (but not `git fetch`) a missing destination means "same as source".

Comment: @tymtam: I didn't go into full refspecs here, as they're another whole confusing aspect of Git...

Comment: Sure, but - I think - the point 2 is about that the *current branch name* will be used for "the thing" (branch name) on the remote i.e. the remote repo will have a branch with the same name. How it's done is secondar from this question's angle.